# Can indirekte Fragesätze only be complemental clauses?

Tags: subordinate-clause, interrogative

Can *indirekte Fragesätze* only be complemental clauses? Can they only be the object/subject of a verb? In what other circumstances can they be part of a sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can also explain adverbials.

> Er stellt die Gläser auf den Tisch.

> Er stellt die Gläser **dorthin,** wo die Flaschen stehen.

> Es passiert immer am Wochenende.

> Es passiert **immer dann**, wenn ich meine Ruhe haben will.

In contrast to English, you need that anchor adverbial as it gives away what kind of adverbial the indirect question fills in for. That's important in German as word order doesn't determine it.

> **Immer dann** mäht der **genau dort** seinen Rasen, wo ohnehin schon alles kahl ist und wenn ich meine Ruhe haben will.

Comment: How come any of these sentences are an "Indirekter Fragesatz"?

Comment: do these subordinate clauses in your examples happen to be Relativsätze?

Comment: @EagleFliesBanana: Your definition of that seems too narrow. To me, it's all clauses that could resemble a question but aren't meant as one.

Comment: @Srmuiel: No, as relative clauses explain a noun. So they act on the level of word class rather than on the level of sentence items.

Comment: **was** can be used as a relative pronoun referring back to a whole clause though...

Comment: @Janka Duden 4 Nr.1553: Bezugselement sind meist Nominal- oder Adverbphrasen. It seems like you're following a more advanced/specialized grammar?

Comment: I follow OPs question. It wasn't about grammar nitpicking but about a practical problem.